# White space below footer in safari

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, mixitup

[this is for safari.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsgg.png)

This is my test website: "http://warmfarewells.org/plumber/" I had this problem in Chrome as well, but I used this code and white space since disappeared. The only problem now is that it is still visible in safari.

```
#cye-workaround-body-image {
    height: auto !important;
}
#cye-workaround-body {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to be working.

PS: I am using Mixit javascript for gallery, when I remove it, both gallery and white space disappears. But I want to keep gallery, and want to get rid of white space. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? It may be a type/bug in your code that Safari is not responding well to. I'm seeing some stuff come through in the Safari web console and not the Chrome web console. Scan your code for any silly errors. Also, feel free to reference the Safari console!

Comment: thank you, is it safe to provide FTP credentials here? because it is test website, so I hope It would be safe..

Comment: @blunor it is never safe to post credentials for your FTP site in a public forum, even if it's a "test" site. Unless you don't mind your server being broken into and people using it for less-than-noble purposes.

Comment: thank you :) I will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is your image animation in the footer.